# How to query Django ORM on models connected with latest record

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

Hi I have a Django Project with the following models

```py
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=128, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField("Description", max_length=256)

class Scholar(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=128)
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=256)
    
    def get_latest_snapshot(self):
        return self.snapshotscholar_set.latest('date_crawled')

class SnapshotScholar(models.Model):
    scholar = models.ForeignKey(Scholar, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_crawled = models.DateTimeField("Date Crawled", auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=256)

class SnapshotScholarPublication(models.Model):
    snapshot_scholar = models.ForeignKey(SnapshotScholar, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=256)
    citation_count = models.IntegerField()
```

Now when I want to get a count of the number of scholars per organization I can do `Organization.objects.annotate(num_scholars=Count('scholar'))`. But how do I get the number of publication per organization when I only want to count publications of the latest snapshot. That is, I want it sorted by SnapshotScholar.date_crawled, and I want all the publications on the latest SnapshotScholar in the database.

Going by some of the questions on here I managed to create this SQL -

```
SELECT COUNT(pub.id) as publications, org.id
FROM (main_snapshotscholarpublication pub, main_snapshotscholar snap, main_scholar scholar, main_organization org)
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(main_snapshotscholar.date_crawled) as latest_date, main_snapshotscholar.scholar_id as 'id'
    FROM main_snapshotscholar
    GROUP BY main_snapshotscholar.scholar_id
) as latest_snap ON (latest_snap.id = snap.id)
WHERE pub.snapshot_scholar_id = snap.id
AND snap.scholar_id = scholar.id
AND scholar.organization_id = org.id
GROUP BY org.id
```

The results I'm getting with this raw SQL is an error margin of 1-5% from the actual count numbers. Can someone please help me figure out how to get the right results?

Thanks

EDIT: As per request of one of the people answering the question here is some sample data - https://pastebin.com/4ZJkymeb . Just load the data with `python manage.py loaddata data.json`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) for getting the results. For example:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery, Q, F, Count

subquery = SnapshotScholar.objects.filter(scholar=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-date_crawled')
queryset = Scholar.objects.annotate(max_scholar_snapshot=Subquery(subquery.values('pk')[:1])).annotate(publication_count=Count('snapshotscholar__snapshotscholarpublication', filter=Q(snapshotscholar=F('max_scholar_snapshot'))))
queryset.values('organization', 'pk', 'publication_count')
```

Here I am first annotating the `SnapshotScholar` information with the queryset by Subquery. I am ordering the `SnapshotScholar` using `date_crawled`, then attaching the latest one's id to the queryset. Then I am running the `Count` for `SnapshotScholarPublication` based on filtering the value of `SnapshotScholar` which was found in last step.

Comment: On the line `queryset = Organization.objects.annotate...` I get an error saying: `ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.`

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I have updated my answer

Comment: No same error. I was looking up the error and it looks like its coming from the `subquery.values('pk')[0]` expression. It doesn't like that for some reason.

Comment: I think this error is for this bug https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29338

Comment: Its not a bug. I made a mistake in query. It should be fixed now

Comment: The query is showing the latest snapshot for only the latest author in the database. It needs to show the latest snapshot for each author. I have edited the question and added a link to some sample data. In that sample data the actual count is 23, but your query shows it as 3.

Comment: Please see the updated answer

Comment: Now the answer shows as 5 where as it should be 23.

Comment: Upvoted! If you are expecting the results to be per organization, instead of `queryset.values('organization', 'pk', 'publication_count')`, try to use: `queryset.values('organization').annotate(organization_publication_count=Count('publication_count'))` to group the results by organization

Comment: @arunkumar I have tested the code in postgres, it seems to be working with your dumpdata. Here is the output I got: https://pastebin.com/uK8vmsri

Comment: Also you can get the total count by: `queryset.aggregate(s=Sum('publication_count'))`

Answer (score 2):

Building up on @ruddra's answer, have a try with this:

```
snapshot_subquery = SnapshotScholar.objects.filter(
    scholar__organization=OuterRef('pk'),
).order_by('-date_crawled')

organizations = Organization.objects.annotate(
    latest_snapshot=Subquery(snapshot_subquery.values('pk')[:1]),
).annotate(
    latest_snapshot_publication_count=Count(
        'scholar__snapshotscholar__snapshotscholarpublication', 
        filter=Q(scholar__snapshotscholar=F('latest_snapshot'))
    ),
)
```

It is important to first order the snapshot scholar by descending `date_crawled`, and then [**`limiting the subquery rows to one row`**..[Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#limiting-the-subquery-to-a-single-row) using slice notation.

Comment: This ran without the error I got for @ruddra 's answer. But the numbers are way off. I'm seeing like 5-10% of the actual value in publication count. The way I'm getting the counts is using properties on each model and counting the numbers I'm getting for each model instance.

Comment: Do you have some sample data and results you can share?

Comment: Also try to add distinct=True on the Count annotation

Comment: This is from a live project, let me see if i can scrub some sample data and upload that on a pastebin or something.

Comment: I have updated the question with sample data as requested. The problem is that the query is giving only the latest snapshot for all the authors. I need the latest snapshot for each author. How do you do that?

Answer (score 1):

I would change your models creating a property in Organization model to get it:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=128, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField("Description", max_length=256)
    @property
    def last_publications_number(self):
        total = 0
        for s in self.scholar_set.all():
            total += s.get_latest_snapshot_publication_number
        return total

class Scholar(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=128)
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=256)
    @property
    def get_latest_snapshot_publication_number(self):
        return self.snapshotscholar_set.order_by('-date_crawled').first().publication_number

class SnapshotScholar(models.Model):
    scholar = models.ForeignKey(Scholar, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_crawled = models.DateTimeField("Date Crawled", auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=256)
    @property
    def publication_number(self):
        return snapshotscholarpublication_set.count()

class SnapshotScholarPublication(models.Model):
    snapshot_scholar = models.ForeignKey(SnapshotScholar, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.ForeignKey("Title", max_length=256)
    citation_count = models.IntegerField()
```

So you can access through:

```
publication_numbers = Organization.objects.get(<whatever>).last_publications_number
```

Comment: This is the approach I'm using currently, and I'm not very happy with it. Because it requires calculations per each record fetched from the database.